# Only SubQuery expressions that are top level conjuncts are allowed

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, exists

I wanted to change an existing query and got the following error:

> Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'deleted': Only SubQuery expressions that are top level conjuncts are allowed

The existing query is:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    *
FROM
    geoposition_import AS geo
-- do not take into account data for deleted users
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM geoposition_import_users AS u 
        WHERE u.id = geo.userId 
            AND NOT u.deleted 
    );
```

After our change, the `userId` in `geoposition_import` can be null, because geo positions can now be created by machines, too. So I changed the query to

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    *
FROM
    geoposition_import AS geo
-- do not take into account data for deleted users
WHERE 
    geo.userId IS NULL -- data from non users (e.g. machines) is still fine
    OR
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM geoposition_import_users AS u 
        WHERE u.id = geo.userId 
            AND NOT u.deleted 
    );
```

and got the error mentioned above.

I googled and found the restrictions: https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/using-hiveql/content/hive_hive_subquery_limitations.html

So my guess is: The OR is the problem.

Now my questions:

1. Why does the error message state, that the 'delete' is the problem?
2. How can I rewrite the query so that it will work?

The only solution that pops into my mind is: split the conditions up into separate views and then do a `UNION ALL`.

Like:

```sql
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS geoposition_import_from_non_users AS
SELECT DISTINCT
    *
FROM
    geoposition_import AS geo
WHERE 
    geo.userId IS NULL;

CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS geoposition_import_from_users AS
SELECT DISTINCT
    *
FROM
    geoposition_import AS geo
-- do not take into account data for deleted users
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM geoposition_import_users AS u 
        WHERE u.id = geo.userId 
            AND NOT u.deleted 
    );

-- staged data with possible duplicates removed
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS geoposition_import_distinct AS
SELECT * FROM geoposition_import_from_non_users
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM geoposition_import_from_users;
```

Any comments?

Comment: what is u.deleted column type? Or what the data is in this column

Comment: @leftjoin boolean. And as I said: The first version without the null check is working fine since years :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try LEFT JOIN instead of EXISTS:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    geo.*
FROM geoposition_import geo
     LEFT JOIN geoposition_import_users u ON u.id=geo.userId AND NOT u.deleted     
WHERE 
    geo.userId IS NULL -- data from non users (e.g. machines) is still fine
    OR u.id IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Ok I'll. But I need to `SELECT DISTINCT geo.*` instead of  `SELECT DISTINCT *` right?